# Sanity GROQ query with Rest API

Tags: rest, sanity, encodeuricomponent, retool

I am trying to query some data from my sanity project in a Retool app. So, I am using [http query](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-query) to send a GROQ GET request to the endpoint:

```
https://<projectId>.apicdn.sanity.io/<YYYY-MM-DD>/data/query/<dataset>?query=*[ _type == 'mytype' && date == '2024-01-17']
```

I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "description": "Unknown query parameter \" date \"",
    "names": [
      " date "
    ],
    "type": "httpUnknownQueryStringParameters"
  }
}
```

I do have a `date` field in my data of type `mytype`.

I think I may need to use `encodeURIComponent()`, but not sure how exactly. Any ideas?